# how to get parent id on Dropdownlist's OnTextChanged event using jquery or javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i want to use jquery's function on dropdownlist's OnTextChanged Event. but i dont know why its not firing. my code is,

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grd_test" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
                width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_test"  OnTextChanged='<%# "return CheckVal(this);" %>' runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="">0</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

my javascript's code is

```
    function CheckVal(obj) {
        var collection = document.getElementById(obj.parentNode.id).getElementsByTagName('SELECT');

        for (var x = 0; x < collection.length - 1; x++) {
            if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase() == 'SELECT-ONE') {
                alert(collection[x].value);
            }
```

}
        }

Comment: raman: you should state your goal at the very top so people can help you out better.  If I understand your posts correctly, you have a repeater with a bunch of dropdownlist bound to it; and you want to ensure that the selected values are unique.  If you are stronger on client side, I would use jQuery.  If you are stronger on the server side, set the dropdownlist to autopostback='true' and bind that OnTextChanged function to a function on your code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that I can't see any jQuery on the code sample you've provided, the select element (i.e. your DropDownList object) uses an OnChange event, not OnTextChanged. If you want something to fire when the user changes the selection this is probably why you're not seeing anything.

Given you have a number of tables, each containing a set of select elements, you're going to want to listen for any change to a given table's select boxes. Here's how you would monitor the change event for each individual table in your repeated gridviews:

```
$('table[id$=drp_test]').each(function(){

   $('select', this).change(function(){
      console.info($('option:selected', this).text());
   });

});
```

This looks at each table on your page whose element ID ends with "drp_test" and adds an event handler to all its select elements.

Now we need to modify this to check the other values from the changed select element's siblings. The end result is that we need to ensure each of the selected options for that table's group is unique.

```
$('table[id$=drp_test]').each(function () {

    var selects = $('select', this);

    // For each select...
    selects.each(function () {
        // Whenever one changes, fire this event
        $(this).change(function () {

            // Gather all the chosen options from this group
            var arr = $.map($('option:selected', selects), function (n) {
                return n.value;
            });

            // And calculate how many unique values we find.
            console.info("The number of duplicated values is " + (arr.length - ($.unique(arr).length)));
        });
    });

});
```

The end result is that you get a count of how many non-unique selected values you have in each table.

Comment: Odd. Looks like an answer from where I sit. Given the ambiguity of the question, how would you answer it?

Comment: sir actually what i want to do the dropdown's value will not be duplicate for it i want parent id of dropdown so that i will check that group only.

Comment: can v chat mr. Phil.Wheeler for a while. if you have time. please

Comment: So when you say you want the parent ID, do you mean you want the ID of the actual DropDown box or you want the ID of whatever element contains that DropDown box?

Comment: Why don't you go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript and we can discuss what it is you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: sir actually the grid containing this dropdown is also inside a repeater. Whats the whole game, i have a repeater inside it i have a grid. now when a user click on repeater's any item its expanding grid will be visible. now the grid contains dropdown. i m asuming the grid to be a group. the group may have 4-5 records. now i want the value selected in dropdown will not be duplicated. these values are static not dyna. as provided the code